# How to fully save model by tf.keras.Model return value and restore it again

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to save the model using `model.save('model.h5')` but it throws error. Look at `def transformer:` model created by function with return value `tf.keras.Model(...)`

It throws

> TypeError: ('Not JSON Serializable:', b'\n...')

https://colab.research.google.com/github/tensorflow/examples/blob/master/community/en/transformer_chatbot.ipynb#scrollTo=-9Oibz2es-qW

Answer (score 0):

Use pickle to dump model object as file

Comment: i already try that, but pickle throwing object error `TypeError: can't pickle _thread.RLock objects`

Comment: So did you find any solution? I have the same problem I tried to create the get_config functions in MultiHeadAttention and in PositionalEncoding and after I reached the same error Not JSON Serializable